# How to remove letters from the end of numbers e.g., 115b, 225c, 19j in a special column in pandas dataframe so they become 115, 225, 19?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove the lowercase letters at the end of numbers in a column `'hole_ID_MWD'` with data like `115b, 225c, 19j`. I want them to be `115, 225, 19`.  I have tried the following:

```
df12['hole_ID_MWD'] = df12['hole_ID_MWD'].str.replace(r'\D+', '', regex=True)
df12['hole_ID_MWD'] = df12['hole_ID_MWD'].str.findall(r'(\d)').str.join('')
df12['hole_ID_MWD'] = df12['hole_ID_MWD'].str.replace('[a-z]', '')
```

But it returns `Nan` values within the column. These `Nan` values are not related to the cells that contain numbers with letters.

input example:

> > df12['hole_ID_MWD']

0 115b
1 225c
2 19j
3 490
4 500
5 600

desired output after using one of the three scripts:

0 115
1 225
2 19
3 490
4 500
5 600

However, What I get is:

0 115
1 225
2 19
3 nan
4 nan
5 600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use regex if all you want is the numeric digits in the column: you can just smiply use `str.isdigit()` to filter out only the numeric digits.

```py
df12["hole_ID_MWD"].apply(lambda x: "".join(i for i in x if i.isdigit()))
Out[17]: 
0    115
1    225
2     19
Name: hole_ID_MWD, dtype: object
```

If you want to use regex, you can use `str.replace` and pass the pattern `"\D+"` (which means one or more non-numeric characters) and replace the match with empty string.

```py
df12["hole_ID_MWD"].str.replace("\D+", "", regex=True)
Out[20]: 
0    115
1    225
2     19
Name: hole_ID_MWD, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you but when I use "df12["hole_ID_MWD"].apply(lambda x: "".join(i for i in x if i.isdigit()))" it gives me type error ;   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @Abboud then your column values are not consistent, try converting to string first as follows: `df12["hole_ID_MWD"].astype(str).apply(lambda x: "".join(i for i in x if i.isdigit()))`